# ffmpeg convert MKV to MP4 while keeping Audio and Subtitle titles

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to batch convert a bunch of MKV videos to MP4 videos. The code I use for this is:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -codec copy -map 0 "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

However, I cannot figure out how to keep the title for each audio track. For example, here is what I see when converting one of my videos:

```
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Director Commentary

 Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Production Commentary
```

While these tracks appear in the converted MP4 file, the titles "Director Commentary" and "Production Commentary" are not kept. I've tried using different variations of map_metadata, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `-map-metadata` as [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/996223/using-ffmpeg-to-copy-metadata-from-one-file-to-another) suggests?

Comment: Yes. If the video output is set to .MKV, then the titles will transfer over. However, if I output it to .MP4 (which is what I would like), then it does not transfer over.

Comment: No matter what I try, the title to all audio files is "SoundHandler" and the title for subtitles is "SubtitleHandler".

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. MP4 does not use "title" when describing the name of audio or subtitle tracks. Apparently it uses "handler".